# Flask-SQLAlchemy association table

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I make a tuition payment app using Flask and using Flask-SQLAlchemy for ORM.

I have a `User` table, and this table I'm using to log in for school account and parent account. While the student data I store it in table `Student` and the student don't have a login account.

What I want to ask for, how to make relationship for the `Student` table to `SCOOL_ID` and `PARENT_ID`..? while the parent account and the school account is in the same table, which is `User` table.

One student have one parent and one student have one school.

Did I must separate the table between the school and the parent..?

So far, I have made it with Flask-SQLAlchemy like this, but I'm not sure this good.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())


association_roles = db.Table('association_roles',
    db.Column('parent_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('school_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)

class Student(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    student_registration_number = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    major = db.Column(db.String(50))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())

    association_roles = db.relationship(
        'Student', secondary=association_roles,
        primaryjoin=(association_roles.c.parent_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(association_roles.c.school_id == id),
        backref=db.backref('student', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
```

So, how to do that..?, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: So just to clarify... you are saying one "student" has a single "parent" and a single "school". However, both "school" and "parent" are stored in the "user" table correct? As such, realistically you have a ONE (Student) to MANY (User) situation, not a many-to-many... so there's no reason to have an association table... am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already know the concept for my question, I must make a table **School** and **Parent** and inherit it from the table **User**, here is snippet of the code:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            default='parent',
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'user',
        'with_polymorphic': '*'
    }

class Parent(User):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    school_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('school.id'))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'parent',
        'with_polymorphic': '*'
    }


class School(User):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'school',
        'with_polymorphic': '*'
    }


class Student(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    school_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('school.id'))
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = db.relationship('Parent', backref=db.backref('Student', lazy='dynamic'))
```